# How to Thread a complex Model class to provide synchronization with a Controller class?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, design-patterns, concurrency, inner-classes

How can I proceed in a controller based on whether just one part of a complex model has produced the correct flag?

A controller class is playing a queue of Midi sequences while holding onto an instance of a model class that is dynamically updated via user button presses.  After the Midi queue ends, the controller needs to synchronize with the model to check that the user has made a certain number of entries before proceeding to update the interface and move to the next part of the application.  The Model represents quite a lot of other data in addition to the ArrayList of user button presses, so the challenge is how to best compartmentalize the synchronization part.

Right now, the pattern I'm trying is something like the following, which doesn't work because of nested class access between the controller and the model:

```
//Controller
...
Thread entriesCoordination = new Thread( new Model.InnerClass);
entriesCoordination.start();

Thread t = new Thread (this);
t.run();

...
//in runnable nested class in controller
private Model.InncerClass c = new Model.InnerClass();
public void run() {
    synchronized( c) { 
        while (!c.hasFinishedEntries()){
            try{
                c.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException ignore{}
            }
        }
    }
    //Midiqueue completed and Entries finished
}
//in Model
//in runnable nested class in Model
public synchronized boolean hasFinishedEntries() {
    return fIsFinishedWithEntries;
}

public void run() {
    while(true) {
        try{
            synchronized(this) {
                try{
                    if(entriesArray.size() == max_size) {
                        fIsFinishedWithEntries = true;
                        notifyAll();
                    } else {...}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Furthermore, this seems wasteful because it basically means that I need to create a thread and run the inner class of the `Model` in parallel the entire duration of the time that the user can make these button selections, rather than something that would just poll the `Model` when I know that the Midi queue has ended.

What's the design pattern to `synchronize` to one flag in a `Model` class from a `Controller` class without having to make a inner class in the model just to handle the synchronization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the right thing to do here is to use an `AtomicBoolean` and define methods on each of your thread objects to get and set the boolean.

The `Model.InnerClass` would be changed to add the `AtomicBoolean` and to change the getter to not be synchronized.

```
private final AtomicBoolean fIsFinishedWithEntries = new AtomicBoolean();
public boolean hasFinishedEntries() {
    return fIsFinishedWithEntries.get();
}
```

In the run method it  something needs to set the finished boolean to be true.

```
public void run() {
    while(true) {
            if (entriesArray.size() == max_size) {
                synchronized (this) {
                    fIsFinishedWithEntries.set(true);
                    notifyAll();
                }
            } else {...}
        }
    }
}
```

You'll need to rest it to `false` somewhere if you are doing this more than once.

> Right now, the pattern I'm trying is something like the following, which doesn't work because of nested class access between the controller and the model:

You need to first create your `Model.InnerClass` instance and *inject* that into your controller thread.  Making the `hasFinishedEntries()` be static is ugly so instead in your controller you'd call:

```
private Model.InnerClass innerClass;
public ControllerThread(Model.InnerClass innerClass) {
    this.innerClass = innerClass;
}
...
public void run() {
    synchronized (innerClass) {
        while (!innerClass.hasFinishedEntries()){
            innerClass.wait();
        }
    }
}
```

> How can I access whether the entries are finished without synchronizing on the entire Model class?

You can obviously just poll the `hasFinishedEntries()` whenever you want to see if the queue has ended.  I'm not sure of a better way to do this without a thread.  Is there some way to setup a UI event which checks for a condition every so often?

Comment: Thanks Gray.  I updated the question to create the `Model.InnerClass` in the controller, as you suggest, @Gray.  I didn't think I really needed an atomic get,set,put on the boolean just because there the controller always gets and model always puts, which wouldn't leave any room for Thread interference from something like interleaved puts.  Overall, are you saying that doing this via these nested "runnable" inner classes is the way to expose synchronization to some part of a model while cleanly separating it from the overall Model class?

Comment: You were looking for a way to see if things had finished _without_ synchronizing.  If you are always going to wait then I'll agree the AtomicBoolean is not necessary.

Comment: Nested `Runnable` inner classes are fine.  You are having problems synchronizing on the inner classes because of visibility with the inner objects.  There are many ways to solve that.  One way would be to put a `hasFinished()` method in the outer class that calls through to the inner class.  You could also have the inner class lock on a `static final Object lockObject = new Object();` in the outer class that other classes can see.  But the outer method call is cleaner.